# Forming a set of pairs in R

Tags: r

I have two sets:

```
{a,b,c,d}  {1,2,3,4}
```

I would like to form a set of pairs  in R:

```
{(a,1), (a,2), (a,3), (a,4), (b,1), (b,2), (b,3), (b,4), (c,1), (c,2), (c,3), (c,4), (d,1), (d,2), (d,3), (d,4)}
```

Comment: Is it  a `python` output or `R`.  Please use `dput` and the packages used

Comment: See `?expand.grid`

Comment: `a1 <- c("a","b","c","d");  
a2 <- c(1,2,3,4);
df <- expand.grid(a1, a2);
df$set_of_pairs <- paste0("(", df[,1], ",", df[,2], ")")`